# Why python does not have any access modifier for constants?

Tags: python, constants

If it was a language design choice, what is the explanation for it?

Is there any other way around this to avoid someone or even myself changing a constant value while executing a program, without having to use an immutable data type?

Comment: What are you using as a constant? could you use an immutable datastructure?

Comment: Couldn't you just not assign anything to that constant?

Comment: You mean a Tuple? it feels a bit dirty to me using a tuple for that when I could have an access modifier.

Comment: Python isn't C. It has a different data model. Don't think in terms of variables (or constants) that contain a value, think in terms of objects (which may or may not be mutable) that are bound to names. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: See also: [Creating constant in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2682745/562769)

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tends to favor simplicity, and uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Python).

In short, the convention is to use underscores for protected/private variables.

Check this as well :

[why python does not have access modifier?And what are there alternatives in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656024/why-python-does-not-have-access-modifierand-what-are-there-alternatives-in-pyth)

Edit1:

If you really want to hide them, you could try this:

```
#constants.py
foo = 1
```

Then on your project, use:

```
import constants
```

And now you have access to them, and "protected".

Comment: The underscore doesn't stop me from changing a constant's value.

Comment: It will not, unless you put all your constant values in their own module.

Comment: @fandressouza: That's where the Python philosophy of "We're all adults here" comes in. The `_` says "You shouldn't." But if you have a legitimate need to do so, Python won't stop you, because it considers you a mature adult, and there are always use cases the original author didn't anticipate.